# application rejected by queue placement policy

Tags: hadoop, hive

I'm using MapR distribution. While i'm trying to run a hive query. Its showing the error- **java.io.ioexception: failed to run job : application rejected by queue placement policy**

I have set the queue with below command,
 **set mapred.job.queue.name=<>;**

But still no use. Could some one help me to understand!!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had this same error.

I used: hadoop queue -showacls | grep SUBMIT to find out the queues I had access to, and then used the command "set mapreduce.job.queuename".

Please do check your Yarn Resource Pool Configuration to make sure you have adequate resources provided for the queue.